# Keras model.fit_generator() gives 0.0% validation accuracy

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a few training images arranged folder wise, few validation images and a few test images. I'm using image generator because the no. of images are not sufficient. I'm using this code:

```
height=150
width=150
channels=3
batch_size=32
seed=1337

# Training generator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,target_size=(height,width),batch_size=batch_size,seed=seed,class_mode='categorical')

# Test generator
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,target_size=(height,width),batch_size=batch_size,seed=seed,class_mode='categorical')
```

and getting an output:

> Found 723 images belonging to 5 classes.
>
> Found 144 images belonging to 5 classes.

And this is my model architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# the model so far outputs 3D feature maps (height, width, features)
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the code for `.fit_generator()`:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000 // 64,
        epochs=5,
        validation_data=test_generator,
        validation_steps=800 // 64)
```

I'm getting an `accuracy` of `70%` after `5 epochs`, but unfortunately `val_acc` and `val_loss` remains `0.00000e+00` and I'm not  quite able to figure it out.
Also I have a folder with 20 images, to be predicted. How do I use `.predict()` function on them? I don't have any `.csv` file where labels are given. Only the training images are given in separate folders, whose name are basically the class of the images.

Comment: Could you post the call to `fit` method as well?

Comment: done, please check

Comment: I could not spot any mistake in your code. The only thing that may be wrong is the `test_dir` path or names of the directories in train and test dirs may be different or the train and test images are very different. Nothing else comes to my mind.

Comment: yaa same even i'm not even able to understand. But if path direction is wrong it wouldn't have been able to detect those 144 images belonging to 5 classes.
Anyway can you tell me what is the code for predicting on new images? After I `fit_generator()` how do I use my `model` to predict on new images?

Comment: No, I mean maybe you have set the path to another directory that also contain images. For prediction using generators you can simply use [`predict_generator`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#predict_generator) function.

Comment: what parameteres do i put inside `predict_generator`? The images to be predicted path directory?

Comment: Have you tried getting sample outputs from your generator and plotting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all fix:

`steps_per_epoch = 2000 // 64
validation_steps = 800 // 64`

to:

`steps_per_epoch = 723 / batch_size
validation_steps = 144 / batch_size`

However, this isn't the issue here. I don't see a problem in your code. I even ran it on my database and it worked fine. As you've been told here, check that the folders in `test_dir` and `train_dir` have the same names.

About `predict_gen`, read the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) of Keras. The output is a vector for each validation image. If you want the string labels you can use the classes list of the generator. So something like:

`pred_Y = np.argmax(model.predict_generator(valid_gen),axis=1)
predicted_labels = [valid_gen.classes[pred_y] for pred_y in pred_Y ]`

Comment: Hi this `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` worked out perfectly.Probably I need to get my basics correct. Thanks so much.

Comment: btw, i'm basically creating a problem statement kind of thing. so i want my validation images to be test set. can i generate any new csv file, kind of a submission file, which can be compared for accuracy with the predicted csv?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to answer that. Did changing `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` solve your problem/?